# Genetic program ( python)

Tags: python

good I'm doing a program which calculates genetically that man inside a list is the fittest to survive but when people eliminate by the command. sends me this error pop can not concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects
how can fix this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! For best results, please update your question with the code that caused the error, steps to reproduce the problem, and the complete description of the error including the error message.

Comment: We need a lot more context and some code samples to be able to help

Answer (score 2):

Somewhere in your Python script you have two values being added together, where one value is a string and the other value is an integer.  This is an error.  Possibly you meant to convert the integer to a string, and concatenate the two strings, or you meant to convert the string to an integer and add the two integers together.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you are trying to concatenate, add, a string and an integer together. This is a no go. Try using the command, `i = int(s)`, to convert your string, `s`, to an integer **or** use the command
`s = str(i)` to convert your integer, `i`, to a string.